# JOIN MySQL doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, join, where-clause

I've tried everything, but nothing works.. Even in an other code I wrote, it works. But for some reason it won't now.

I want to join two tables where the ID = userID. When I load the page, I get this error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
>   result resource in
>   /home/ynxwleus/domains/mustseenmovies.nl/public_html/films/userinfo.php
>   on line 17

Is there anyone who can help me with this problem?

**Code:**

```
$userID = $_SESSION['s_userID'];
        echo $userID;
        $query = "SELECT userID, userName, userFrontname, userSurname, filmID 
        FROM users
        JOIN seenIt
        ON users.userID = seenIt.userID 
        WHERE (userID ='$userID')";

        $res = mysql_query($query);
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
                    echo $row['userName'];
                    echo $row['userFrontname'];
                    echo $row['userSurname'];
                    echo $row['filmID'];
                }
```

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: upvoted the answer, but as a side note you should really consider using mysqli instead of the deprecated mysql.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your where clause needs an alias:

```
    WHERE (users.userID ='$userID')
```

Your select clause also needs an alias on the userId:

```
    SELECT users.serID, userName, userFrontname, userSurname, filmID
```

In fact, it is a really good idea to *ALWAYS* use aliases:

```
SELECT u.userID, u.userName, u.userFrontname, u.userSurname, si.filmID 
FROM users u join
     seenIt si
    ON u.userID = si.userID 
WHERE u.userID ='$userID'
```

The original query has syntax errors, because the SQL engine does not know which `userID` is being referred to.  Oh, you are thinking "that's obvious because `on` clause specifies that the values are the same."  Well, humans are smarter than SQL compilers, at least when it comes to common sense.

Comment: @DannyPostma You'll need an alias here too; `SELECT users.userID, userName...`

Comment: Yeah, just noticed it. Thanks alot! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

If your query returns an error, then `mysql_query` returns a boolean `false`. You can print out this error using `mysql_error()`.

```
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Additionally, `mysql_fetch_row` will not work on a boolean, so you get the compilation error.

Your query has an error, as Gordon pointed out.

Additionally, I would suggest to not use `mysql` anymore, since it is deprecated. Use `MySQLi`, or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT userID, userName, userFrontname, userSurname, filmID 
          FROM users
          JOIN seenIt
          WHERE users.userID = seenIt.userID 
          AND  users.userID = ".$userID." ";
```

Comment: Very bad!! This code is vulerable to SQL Injections!

Comment: Please add some explanations.